# How do I send a large form to a REST API in express?

Tags: reactjs, api, rest, express

In the front-end (React) there is a form with almost 50 fields. Now, my API in Express, is taking all the fields as `x-www-form-urlencoded`. Front-end says it's too many fields and there should be a simpler way to send them and accept them in back-end.

I'm not too sure what the solution would be. How can I minimize those 50 fields into just a few keys?

I understand the question is quite broad, but here's an example of how the keys might look like:
`name`,
`surname`,
`locationName_1`,
`locationAddress_1`,
`Latitude_1`,
`longitude_1`,
`someOtherField`,
`otherfieled`,
`locationName_2`,
`locationAddress_2`,
`Latitude_2`,
`longitude_2`,
...

I'm returning a big object with all those form data too. I would like to know if there are some design patterns which I should look into.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've never sent 50 fields at once, but I'm curious, do you have
`app.use(express.urlencoded())` in your `app.js` (Express API) with certain configs?

I do know that when a server does not have `app.use(express.urlencoded())` the data is not usefull because of this: `x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: Yes I have the `app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));` in my server. What would be a good way of sending 50 fields at once? Does it even make sense as a best practice (or good practice)